# Transferring MapInfo TAB to PostGIS using FME?

Tags: postgis, fme-form, tab

I am using FME to try and  transfer hundreds of MapInfo TAB files into PostGIS.

I know how to get the tables into PostGIS using FME but  I cannot work out how to transfer the styles of the MapInfo tables over.

For example, council owned land has a style of red polygons in my MapInfo TAB file, I want to keep those saved red polygons when taking the layer to PostGIS but I lose the style of the layer in the process.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: What software are you using to display the PostGIS data?

Comment: QGIS to display the data, once it is in PostGIS

Comment: You can get all the information into the table, but while QGIS allows styling with rules, I am not aware of a mechanism to read the style itself from the data. I guess you have to add QGIS rules like "Council→red". (You could also use "fme_fill_color→red" rules, but that would still require one rule per value.)

Answer (score 5):

MapInfo is a format that can store style information. In FME you can read this data using format attributes. For the red polygons you would be looking for `fme_color` and `fme_fill_color`. Just go to the format attributes tab in the feature type and expose the ones you want.

[image: MapInfo FME format attributes]

More info in the documentation: http://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/mapinfo_extended/Feature_Representation.htm

However, your problem is that PostGIS doesn't store style information natively. You might use an external style file or other options depending on where you are displaying your data. What you can always do is transferring the style information of the MapInfo format attributes into PostGIS attributes so you can use them after for styling.

Comment: Specifically, the mapinfo_brush and mapinfo_pen attributes are relevant.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to tick these options but I am still having no luck

Comment: You will also need to add them on the other side of the workspace. On the right-hand object, open the parameters dialog and click User Attributes. In the list of attributes being created you will need to create two new attributes to store this information. Then use an AttributeCopier transformer to copy the FME attributes into your new user attributes